# how to convert include and then include in entity framework to MySQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have some code using Entity framework like this

```
public class Userpayment
    {
        public List<managerpayment> Managerpayments{ get; set; }

        public accountpayment Accountpayments{ get; set; }
        public adminpayment Adminpayment{ get; set; }
    }
```

And here I am using include and then include like this

```
var withIncludes = await _userpayment
                .Where(x => x.ManagerId == managerId)
                .Include(t => t.managerpayment)
                .Include(t => t.accountpayment)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.adminpayment)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();



 return withIncludes
             .Select(x =>
                 new
                 {
                     _userpayment= x,
                     managerpayment= x.managerpayment.OrderByDescending(z => z.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                     accountpayment= x.accountpayment
                 })
             .Where(m => m.managerpayment!= null)
```

I am trying to convert this to MySQL query and ended up like this

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
   `userpayment` `uspm`
    JOIN `managerpayment` `mup` ON `mup`.`map_id` = `uspm`.`map_id` 
    JOIN `accountpayment` `msam` ON `msam`.`buyer_id` = `uspm`.`map_id`
    JOIN `adminpayment` `amp` ON `amp`.`map_id` = `msam`.`map_id`
where 
    `uspm`.`manager_id`=managerId
```

Couple of questions here---

Is this how internally EntityFramework converts??

how to convert `managerpayment= x.managerpayment.OrderByDescending(z => z.Id).FirstOrDefault()` this to mysql --since managerpayment is a list i want to do orderbydescending and perform join

and how to add this condition `Where(m => m.managerpayment!= null)`

Comment: Why don't you just run the LINQ query and see what EF makes of it?

Comment: can you explain how to do that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli